# Create random column based on data in R

Tags: r, merge

I need to create a simulation data and I have a problem combining two column in R. I have two `vectors`, for example:

```
    product <- c("prod_A", "prod_B", "prod_C", "prod_D", "prod_E")
    chemical <- c("chemA", "chemB", "chemC")
```

I need to create two columns based on product and the chemical inside it.

For example, the final result should be like something like:

```
    Product   Chemical

    Prod_A    chemA
              chemB

    Prod_B    chemB
              chemC

    Prod_C    chemA
              chemC

    Prod_D    chemA

    Prod_E    chemA
              chemB
              chemC
```

Comment: Try `expand.grid(product, chemical)` or with `tidyverse` `crossing(product, chemical) %>% mutate(product = replace(product, duplicated(product), ""))`

Comment: Why does productA only has chemA & chemB? What are the rules?

Comment: The statement "I have two `data.frame`" is incorrect. You have two _vectors_ not dataframes, please clarify whether your input should really be data.frames

Comment: @Sotos there is no rule. it is totally random.

Comment: Noted @avid_useR. Thanks

Comment: @avid_useR Agreed. I reopened. OP needs to clarify what they mean by `random`. How many elements in each? We need some more information to go on

Comment: Should the number of chemicals per product also be random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sample` to create a random sample of `chemical`s for each `product` using `group_map`. This assumes that both the `chemical`s being drawn and the number of samples are random:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

tibble(product) %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  group_map(~ tibble(Chemical = sample(chemical, sample(seq_along(chemical)))))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
# Groups:   product [5]
   product Chemical
   <chr>   <chr>   
 1 prod_A  chemC   
 2 prod_B  chemC   
 3 prod_B  chemB   
 4 prod_B  chemA   
 5 prod_C  chemB   
 6 prod_C  chemA   
 7 prod_C  chemC   
 8 prod_D  chemC   
 9 prod_E  chemC   
10 prod_E  chemB   
11 prod_E  chemA
```

Note that `group_map` is currently experimental, so please use with caution. An alternative would be to `split`, `map` and `rbind` the results, which is essentially what `group_map` is doing.